# Which video card upgrade for early 2008 Mac Pro?

Tags: mac, graphics-card

I've got an early 2008 Mac Pro, and would really like to upgrade my video card beyond the stock Radeon 2600 HD that came with my system.  I run two DVI monitors (neither of which accepts the Mini DisplayPort connector).  I'd also like to get a card that will work well for Windows games under Boot Camp.  So it seems like my options are:

- ATI Radeon 3870 Mac and PC edition - Cheap, but not sold by the Apple store and I hear it's pretty noisy.
- ATI Radeon 4870 - Mid-price, sold by the Apple store, but has one DVI port and one Mini DisplayPort.  I have heard bad things about the Mini DisplayPort to DVI converter.
- NVIDIA GTX 285 - Cool but pretty expensive.

Has anybody had any experience with any of these cards?  Can anyone confirm or deny the noise issues with the 3870 or the non-working DisplayPort to DVI adapter?  Are there any options I haven't thought of?

Comment: I thought when you wanted to upgrade a mac you just threw it away and bought a new one....

Comment: Never had any problem with the DisplayPort-to-DVI converters - we have about 15 of them. Not used any with the 4870 though.

Comment: The only bad thing about the mini DP to DVI connector is the fact that you have to buy one, I've used one on my MBP with zero problems.

Comment: Thanks for the info on the DP to DVI connectors!  Maybe the reports I've heard are user errors.

Comment: @Hardwareguy Nah, with the Mac Pro, you get one round of upgrades, and THEN you throw it away and buy a new one!

Comment: FWIW, I ended up saving my pennies and getting the GTX 285.  It's quiet and works quite well, though it's turned my Mac into even more of a space heater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anandtech was pretty impressed with the GTX 285 (here's their review) http://www.anandtech.com/video/showdoc.aspx?i=3603 but you could try updating the firmware on a PC version to save a few bucks, though you'd still need to buy the power adapters from apple.